# Angular: Accessing Variables in a Function

Tags: html, angular, scss-lint

I'm not sure how to access "this" from a function in Angular.

This is my HTML

```
    <img id="castle_frame_0" [ngClass]="this.frame == 0 ? 'show' : 'hide'" src="../../assets/FC_Frame_0.png">
    <img id="castle_frame_1" [ngClass]="this.frame == 1 ? 'show' : 'hide'" src="../../assets/FC_Frame_1.png">
    <img id="castle_frame_2" [ngClass]="this.frame == 2 ? 'show' : 'hide'" src="../../assets/FC_Frame_2.png">
    <img id="castle_frame_3" [ngClass]="this.frame == 3 ? 'show' : 'hide'" src="../../assets/FC_Frame_3.png">
    <img id="castle_frame_4" [ngClass]="this.frame == 4 ? 'show' : 'hide'" src="../../assets/FC_Frame_4.png">
    <img id="castle_frame_5" [ngClass]="this.frame == 5 ? 'show' : 'hide'" src="../../assets/FC_Frame_5.png">
```

I'm basically trying to change the frames every X seconds to make one of the characters blink. This is my component so far:
[image]

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please, use `src="./assets/FC_Frame_0.png"` or `src="assets/FC_Frame_0.png"`. Angular copy your assets folder in the same folder the index.html is. Think that Angular doesn't matter the relative direction of your folder assets with the folder your component is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically the approach you have described, you just need to put it into your code. Below is one way you can do it

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  frame = 0;
  refresh = 2000;
  maxFrames = 5;

  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.blink()
    }, this.refresh); // will call the blink function after every 2 seconds
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.frame = 1; 
    console.log(this.frame);
  }

  blink() {
    // If frame is 0 then set it to some other number between 1 and 5 else set it back to 0;
    this.frame = this.frame === 0 ? this.getRandom(1, this.maxFrames)  : 0;
  }

  getRandom(min: number, max: number){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
}
```

After every 2 seconds it will change to 0 and stay 0 for 2 seconds then change to a random number between 1-5 and stay that for 2 seconds.

Here is a [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-csbraa?file=src%2Fmain.ts) where you can play with this code and see this in action

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I'm having issues with scope now... I think? I can't access "this.frame" from blink. If I could, I might not have needed to post on StackOverflow. Now I'm messing around with const variables... but no luck.

Comment: The specific error I get when trying to access "this.frame" is as follows: "'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683) home.component.ts(23, 10): An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container."

Comment: the blink function needs to be part of this `HomeComponent` class if not then you will to write code to synchronize the values.. If you see in my demo `blink` is a class method

Comment: This was exactly right. I was tripping over the syntax.